# Read File that has Float values as Array

Tags: java, arrays, file, file-upload

I have a file that has some float values and I am trying to read them but its not working
the file is like this:

```
[0.97265625, 0.96484375, 0.9765625, 0.9765625, 0.97265625, 0.97265625, 0.97265625, 0.97265625, 0.9765625, 0.9765625, 0.9765625, 0.9765625, 0.9765625, 0.9765625]
```

I get an input mismatch error so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File txt = new File("C:/Users/User1/Documents/rboukarf_hard.txt");

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txt);
        try{
        String print = "";
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {

            System.out.println(scanner.nextFloat());
                if (scanner.nextFloat() < 1){
                    print = print + "0 ";

                }
                else {
                    print = print + "2 ";


            print = print + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(print);
    }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown: " + e);
        }
}
```

Comment: You know you're calling `nextFloat` twice in the loop right…?

Comment: I get an input mismatch exception

Comment: `scanner.useDelimiter(",[ \r\n]*");` will be needed (hoping those square braces are not in the file)

Answer (score 0):

Something like (see my comment about square brackets)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File txt = new File("floats.txt");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txt);
            scanner.useDelimiter(",[ \r\n]*");
            String print = "";
            while (scanner.hasNextFloat()) {

                if (scanner.nextFloat() < 1) {
                    print = print + "0 ";

                } else {
                    print = print + "2 ";

                    print = print + "\n";
                }
                System.out.println(print);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown: " + e);
        }
    }
```